# how to embed a webpage using wx?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I need to show a webpage (a complex page with script and stuff, no static html) in a frame or something. It's for a desktop application, I'm using python 2.6 + wxPython 2.8.10.1. I need to catch some events too (mostly about changing page). I've found some samples using the webview module in a gtk application, but I couldn't have it works on wx.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed IE, but I think that's about it. wxWebKit is working on a wx add-on to use WebKit as an embedded browser in wx, but I think it's still a work in progress.

Comment: yeah, i tried to build it up on my ubuntu, but i had to give up after a long fight against missing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial solution for this called [wxWebConnect](http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html) that uses Gecko (the Mozilla engine). I've never used it myself because i'm waiting for the wxWebKit project to be ready to use but it looks pretty good although perhaps a little overkill for your needs.

Comment: I think wxWebConnect is free? It's source can be downloaded, and I can't find a price or sales info. I think Kirix used it in a commercial project (a data-mining app) and released the source.

Comment: yup, just noticed wxwebconnect is released under wxWindows Library License Version 3.1, so yay :) thank you all for the info, i'll give it a try.

Comment: just figured out there's no python wrappers for wxwebconnect, i will try to build wxwebkit after all.